# Logitech MX Keys sends incorrect modifier keys

Tags: centos, keyboard

I'm running CentOS 7 on a Dell laptop.  The native keyboard works correctly, but my Logitech MX Keys keyboard is sending some incorrect modifiers:

- Pressing <kbd>L WIN</kbd> triggers <kbd>L ALT</kbd>
- Pressing <kbd>L ALT</kbd> triggers <kbd>L WIN</kbd>
- Pressing <kbd>R ALT</kbd> triggers <kbd>R WIN</kbd> (the keyboard lacks <kbd>R WIN</kbd>)
- Pressing <kbd>R CTRL</kbd> triggers <kbd>R ALT</kbd>
- <kbd>Insert</kbd> key is not detected at all

Default xbkmap settings:

```
$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105+inet
layout:     us,us
variant:    ,
options:    terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
```

I tried using options to fix the problem:

```
$ setxkbmap -option altwin:swap_alt_win
$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105+inet
layout:     us,us
variant:    ,
options:    terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,altwin:swap_alt_win
```

This fixes the left modifiers and <kbd>R ALT</kbd>, but now:

- Pressing <kbd>R CTRL</kbd> triggers <kbd>R WIN</kbd>

So I took a stab at combining another swap option:

```
$ setxkbmap -option ctrl:swap_rwin_rctl
$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105+inet
layout:     us,us
variant:    ,
options:    terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,altwin:swap_alt_win,ctrl:swap_rwin_rctl
```

But that made it worse:

- <kbd>R ALT</kbd> triggers <kbd>R CTRL</kbd>
- <kbd>R CTRL</kbd> triggers <kbd>R WIN</kbd>

I looked through the options at `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst`, but can't find any that address my particular situation.
I'd prefer a persistent solution, but I'm willing to add it to my startup scripts if need be.
I don't use the native keyboard, so I'm ok with a solution that breaks it.

Comment: The moral of https://superuser.com/a/1515035/38062 is to always read the user manual.  (-:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[JdeBP's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/600178/external-keyboard-sends-incorrect-modifier-keys#comment1120650_600178) led me to [Logitech's setup instruction for MX Keys](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/promo/mxsetup/keyboard-setup/wireless-receiver.html), which indicate <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> for Mac and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> for Windows/Linux/Chrome.  I recall taking the current Logitech Unifying Adapter from a MacBook, so I probably previously configured it for that and forgot.

I cleared all of my previous Xkb options and set the keyboard to Windows/Linux/Chrome mode.  This fixed all of the keys, even after a reboot.

From what I can tell, these OS-specific configurations are tied individually to each of the 3 preset connection keys.  When I was using the keyboard on both Windows and Mac machines, I never recall having to repeat the OS-specific keystrokes.  This is likely why I forgot about the feature.

Comment: Summary: WINDOWS/LINUX: Fn + P. MACOS: Fn + O. Hold for 3 seconds.