# Invert Fn button behavior

Tags: keyboard-layout

I have just received a Logitech MX Keys keyboard which has a very annoying flaw, as you can see:

[image]

The first line is inverted (actions instead of `F1` to `F12`), so it requires to use the `Fn`.

I was betting on `xmodmap` sadly some keys (ie.`F1` and `F2` keys, without `Fn`) are not catched by `xev`.

I am using the default Generic (86 keys) layout in KDE/Archlinux, is there a better layout or a way to "invert" these keys?

Comment: Doesn't it work as you want if you hold down the "Fn" key (next to the right Alt) and then press Esc to turn on Fn lock?

Comment: Very similar is https://superuser.com/questions/735062/how-to-invert-the-fn-key

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual flaw is that you haven't read the doco.  ☺  As I said at [Logitech MX Keys sends incorrect modifier keys](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/600178/5132) , the moral is to always read the user manual.

<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> is the chord for <kbd>Fn Lock</kbd> on your keyboard, as explained both in Logitech's *Getting Started* doco and in its FAQ document for the keyboard.

## Further reading

- *[Getting Started MX Keys](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360034762774-Getting-Started-MX-Keys)*.  Logitech Support.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2020). *[The "Fn" key is local.](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/fn-key-is-local.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.

Comment: It's not so obvious, but thank you @JdeBP